# Android random intent with array

Tags: android, android-intent, random

Hello i have a quiz with 2000 questions in my app and i want to start a random intent when clicking the button. But my code does not work. i don`t know what is wrong with it. to make it easier to display it here i putted only 4 strings in the array

```
public void KlickA (View view) {

     final String[] fragen = {"Frage1Activity.class","Frage2Activity.class","Frage3Activity.class","Frage4Activity.class"};
    Button buttonfrag = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fragzufall);
    buttonfrag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
     int random = (int) (Math.random() *4 );
    Intent intent = new Intent(fragen[random]);
    startActivity(intent);
    }});    
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Please do not start a Activity for every question, just change the text of your views. It gets you in real trouble. You have to declare every Activity in your Manifest.xml, you arent able to do global changes and so on. For your next question please add your logcat to it!

Comment: Why not launch one activity and then randomly pick a question to display and process the display of that question in the activity's onCreate()? You can use Fragment for different types of questions.

Comment: i have an activity for each question for checking wheter the answers are correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String[] fragen = {"Frage1Activity.class","Frage2Activity.class","Frage3Activity.class","Frage4Activity.class"};
```

For your intent you must write something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,fragen[random]); // error here !!!
```

**here you have**  :

`fragen[random]` is a `String` but it must be somthing like :

`Frage3Activity.class` //class not String

**not like** :  `"Frage3Activity.class"// string`

---

**Solution :**

use:

`Class cl = Class.forName(fragen[random]);`

then :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cl);
```

Finally :

```
 public void KlickA (View view) {
    final String[] fragen = {"Frage1Activity.class","Frage2Activity.class","Frage3Activity.class","Frage4Activity.class"};
    Button buttonfrag = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fragzufall);
    buttonfrag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           int random = (int) (Math.random() *4 );
           Class cl = Class.forName(fragen[random]);
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cl);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the activity name in Manifest?

it should be something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, fragen[random]);
```

Comment: i tried it with this but it gave me the error "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String) is undefined"

Comment: gave it a update you have to reference to the Activity

Comment: Yes the activities are set in the manifest and if start them without the random button they work.

Comment: fragen[random] is a String -.-

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the intent creation. If you create an intent with a String, that means you want to create an intent with an action, not the class. In your case, you want to create the intent with explicit class (like Frag1Activity.class), you can try creating intent with a different constructor:

```
//Create an intent for a specific component.
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

For example, the following is how I start an DetailActivity with an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
intent.setAction("View");
intent.putExtra("category", itemSelected.category);
intent.putExtra("entree_name", itemSelected.name);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create Intent array like this:

```
Intent[] intentArray = {new Intent(this, Frage1Activity.class), new Intent(this, Frage2Activity.class), 
    new Intent(this, Frage3Activity.class), new Intent(this, Frage4Activity.class)};


int random = (int) (Math.random() *4 );
Intent intent = intentArray[random];
```